# Calculating columns when upgrading to ui-grid 3.0 from ng-grid

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I have a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xCx8tjhbmltTvJCe17Ht?p=preview) to demonstrate my issues.

[1](http://plnkr.co/edit/xCx8tjhbmltTvJCe17Ht?p=preview) Issue: Totals column is blank

I need to calculate the columns (Total) so I have a $scope method as follows:

```
$scope.getTotal = function(a, b, c, d, e) {
    return $filter('number')(Number(a) + Number(b) + Number(c) + Number(d) + Number(e), 2);
  };
```

and the cellTemplate to make that call:

```
<div class="padd black">
 {{getExternalScopes().getTotal(row.entity.M,row.entity.T,row.entity.W,row.entity.H,row.entity.F)}}
</div>
```

and in columnDefs, I use:

```
{
      field: 'total',
      displayName: 'Total',
      enableColumnMenu: false,
      type: 'number',
      cellFilter: 'number:1',
      cellClass: 'text-right',
      headerCellClass: 'text-center',
      cellTemplate: 'total.tmpl.html',
      width: '10%'
    }
```

[2] Issue: ng-class not working in template, pending.icons.html

We use icons to indicate status of a record and in the template, I am using a conditional for ng-class which should control the color of the icon but it is being ignored and all icons are colored black:

```
ng-class="{'cBlue': grid.getCellValue('vote_pending'), 'cGray': !grid.getCellValue('need_vote')}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhh, this answer may only be a partial.

Since v3 the external scopes are (probably) gone and have been replaced by `grid.appScope.function_xxx()`. Read more [here](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/305_appScope)

So you have to leave out the external scopes part in your markup:

```
 <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-edit ui-grid-cellNav class="grid"></div>
```

The function for calculation in your scope should be:

```
  $scope.getTotal=function(a, b, c, d, e) {
    return a+b+c+d+e;
  };
```

*(I left the filtering and number stuff out)*

And your cell template would now be:

```
<div class="padd black">
 {{grid.appScope.getTotal(row.entity.M,row.entity.T,row.entity.W,row.entity.H,row.entity.F)}}
</div>
```

This seems to work here: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/A0I82mj8p3SIQlyjWP4N?p=preview)

Since I'm on my way home now, I'll check for your 2nd Issue later.

Hope this helps so far.

**Update:**

2nd Issue:

Use this in `pending.icons.html` :

```
 ng-class="{'cBlue': row.entity.vote_pending, 'cGray': !row.entity.vote_pending}"
```

Works for me (allthough my Plunker is very, veeery slow at the moment)

Look [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/GwJVYiyGgtbVWW2x6CZ4?p=preview)

Comment: absolutely perfect ... I should have caught the external scopes from the docs but I totally missed that ... thanks!!!